# yii 2.0 carousel of images stored in a specific folder

Tags: php, jquery, yii, yii2

In my Yii 2.0 application i store images per provider in a separate folder. I want to show the images in that provider folder as a carousel with filmstrip without having to store the filenames in the database. Is there an option in Yii 2.0 to do that, or is there an extension that could show a carousel just based upon a folder location?
Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0):

I googled around and tried different options and now it works for me with this setup. The $items goes into the extension (the slick Yii 2.0 extension in this case and create the slider for me. Maybe useful for others that are starting to work with the Yii framework like me.

```
<?php
    $image_dir = "images/banners/";
    $images_array = preg_grep('~\.(jpeg|jpg|png)$~', scandir($image_dir));
    foreach($images_array as $image_name){
        $image_full_path = Url::home().$image_dir.$image_name;
        $items[] = (Html::img($image_full_path));
    }        
?>
```